# Retrieve/export datapoints from Linkit One Mediatek iCloud sandbox

Tags: jquery, sandbox

I has try to retrieve the data from sandabox using Jquery, my code as below

```
$.ajax({ 
 type: "GET", 
  url: "https://api.mediatek.com/mcs/v2/devices/xxxxx/datachannels/AcceBreak/datapoints?limit=1000", 
 headers: { deviceKey: "cccxxxxxx" }, 
 contentType: "application/json" 
}) 

$.each(data["dataChannels"][0].dataPoints[0].values, function (key, element) { 
  alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element); 
})
```

But I only get the last point data, the previous data not able to get.

I have try https://api.mediatek.com/mcs/v2/devices/xxxxx/datachannels/AcceBreak/datapoints.csv but it gave me error "No permission". 
Any mistake I make, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "https://api.mediatek.com/mcs/v2/devices/xxxxx/datachannels/AcceBreak/datapoints?limit=1000", 
    headers: { deviceKey: "cccxxxxxx" }, 
    contentType: "application/json" 
    }) 
    var data={};
    $.each(data["dataChannels"][0].dataPoints[0].values, function (key, element) { 
    data[key]=element;
     })
    alert(data);
```